# Why is the integrability condition necessary in this change of variable formula?

Tags: measure-theory

I've been trying to figure out why we need the integrability condition in the following change of variable formula. Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be Borel measurable, and $Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined for all $\omega \in \Omega$ by $Y(\omega) = f(X(\omega))$.

> If $\int_{\Omega}|Y|dP < \infty$, then $\int_{\Omega}YdP = \int_{\mathbb{R}}fP_{X}$, where $P_{X}$ is the probability measure induced by $X$.

Despite my best efforts I've not been able to come up with an example where $\int_{\Omega}|Y|dP = +\infty$ and $\int_{\Omega}YdP \neq \int_{\mathbb{R}}fP_{X}$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The condition is just necessary to ensure that the integrals are both well-defined. As long as $Y_+$ or $Y_-$ is integrable, the formula holds. If neither of these is integrable, then both sides of the equation are ill-defined.

Comment: But $\int_{\Omega}|Y|dP < \infty$ implies that both $\int_{\Omega}Y^{+}dP$ and $\int_{\Omega}Y^{-}dP$ are $< \infty$?

Comment: I think it's because usually in text books, they put integrability condition to simplify. In many situation, semi-integrability condition is enough.

Comment: Yes, that's why it is sufficient that $Y$ is absolutely integrable. But you can gemeralize it to the fact that is only needs to be semiintegrable.

Comment: Take a look at "Real Analysis and Probability" by Robert B. Ash. He defines the integral as a number of $[-\infty, +\infty]$ and then show that they are both equal in the sense that if they exist, they coincide (in the extended real line) or that neither exist.